# becomeFirstResponder do not display keyboard in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

I have 4 TextField align together and each is with a tag (1, 2, 3, 4), it works as a code input. i want to make sure when ever i clicked or tap else where the current field of the code input it will make the current field as its first responder.

Example scenario

1 _ _ _

if i clicked else where the first text field it should point focus on the first textfield

Using the code below i was able to do so BUT the problem is keyboard don't appear if there is no current first responder with in the code input.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.tag != currentTag {
        let currentResponder = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(currentTag) as? UITextField
        currentResponder?.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: what's exact problem? keyboard doesn't appear on tapping textfield ?

Comment: set currentTag = 1 defaultly.i m not sure if i understood ur qus correctly

Comment: @bhanupriya yes, keyboard don't appear, i think i break the keyboard before it is create, because in the process of becoming first responder, i immediately change the first responder. i also figure out the answer.

rather than using textFieldDidBeginEditing i use textFieldShouldBeginEditing

Comment: my answer `code` 

`func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField.tag != currentTag {
            let currentResponder = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(self.currentTag) as? UITextField
            currentResponder?.becomeFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }`

Comment: if there is no condition on text, textfield automatically appear, no need to write code to handle

Answer (score 3):

Here our custom responder is overlaping with the default responder of the tapped textfield so i delayed it 0.1 sec and calling the responder

**Swift 3**

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
if textField.tag != currentTag {
    let currentResponder = textField.superview?.viewWithTag(currentTag) as? UITextField
    currentResponder?.perform(
                #selector(becomeFirstResponder),
                with: nil,
                afterDelay: 0.1
            )
    }
}
```